# get_absolute_url() with multiple args

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

[models.py](http://pastebin.com/zB3UhTRY), [urls.py](http://pastebin.com/b1pC2Z8M), [views.py](http://pastebin.com/BDvTMtzJ)

I'm trying to set a `get_absolute_url()` function for the `Entry` class, but failing. I have successfully created such a function for the `Category` class, with only one arg, but am stuck on using multiple args as in the `Entry` class.

Currently, clicking a

```
<a href="/blog/{{ entry.get_absolute_url }}/">{{ entry.title }}</a>`
```

link, as appears on my index page, only returns the url below:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog//
```

I originally used returns without reverse like this:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/%s/%s/%s/" % (self.pub_date.year, self.pub_date.month, self.slug)
```

but, whilst it worked from index.html with the earlier mentioned `href`, from other pages (i.e. `category.html`) this returned a URL with this appended upon the current URL, including for the `Category` class. Switching to reverse fixed this issue for `Category`, but I couldn't get it to work for `Entry`, because of the multiple args.

Please request any additional data as is desirable.

---

**Edit:** Well, I've managed to make it work with(the original code):

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "%s/%s/%s/%s" % (self.pub_date.year, self.pub_date.month, self.pub_date.day, self.slug)
```

by changing the `href` at category.html to:

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/{{ entry.get_absolute_url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
```

i.e. I added the root `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, but I still can't get it to work with `reverse()`... I've tried `args`, `kwargs`, some other things... I'm not actually sure still what `reverse()` does differently though to a regular `return`. It did something differently, as before when I was using the `"blog/{{ category.get_absolute_url }}"` without the root, switching from `return` to `return reverse()` made it work; although I've now managed to get it to work with just `return`, by adding the root to the `href` as I did with `Entry`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `kwargs` with reverse. Something like:

Assuming your url pattern for blog detail is like:

```
url(r'^blog/(?P<year>)/(?P<month>)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'details', name='blog_details')
```

You can write get_absolute_url as:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog_details', kwargs={'year': self.pub_date.year,
                                     'month': self.pub_date.month,
                                     'slug': self.slug})
```

And use it in template as you are using.

Comment: what's not working? Did you change your get_absolut_url to use reverese with kwargs?

Comment: Yes, I did it exactly as you wrote.

Comment: Your regex isn't quite right here: should be `(?P<year>\d{1,2})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})`...

Comment: Heh, well I tried that as well already Daniel =D I tried it as he put it first, then made some adjustments like what you suggested and that didn't work either. >_< I made an edit with some updated info to the original question though.